# How to zero out a disk

Tags: security, disk-management

What's the easiest way to write over a hard disk (such that you could give it to a friend, etc.) on elementary OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run **`sudo fdisk -l`** to determine which **`/dev/sdX`** drive you will rewrite. (The drives are listed in an order: `sda` for your main drive, `sdb`, `sdc`, etc. for your remaining drives.) Use that path in place of **`sdX`** in the next command:
2. Run **`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX status=progress`** to write zeros to your disk. (`status=progress` is a recent addition to see the process's status—it might not work on your system.)

If you'd prefer to use a GUI, [`gdiskdump`](https://launchpad.net/gdiskdump) is relatively straightforward, but I think the above is easier than installing software for a single operation. To install, run `sudo apt install gdiskdump`.